# Fill 3d ('levelled') array with 2d weights and level indices

Tags: numpy

My overall goal is convert a bunch of 3d ('levelled') climate data files into 2d by "projecting" them onto a target topography, making use of the level topographies. Since the climate data files are identically levelled I am constructing a projection matrix that can then be applied to each file individually. Here I am constructing this projection matrix, which is nothing more than a 3d weights matrix containing some linear interpolation weights:

```
wgt = np.ma.zeros((nlat,nlon,nlev))
print(wgt.shape)
> (2700, 1496, 11)
```

So far, I was able to come up with the necessary weights (`wgt_A`, `wgt_B` -- both 2d) and corresponding levels indices (`lev_idx-1`, `lev_idx`) using `np.digitize`. The remaining step is to construct the 3d weights matrix using these weights and indices. I have this implementation:

```
for ii in range(nlat):
   for jj in range(nlon):
      wgt[ii,jj,lev_idx[ii,jj]-1] = wgt_A[ii,jj]
      wgt[ii,jj,lev_idx[ii,jj]]   = wgt_B[ii,jj]
```

But I am wondering if there's a faster, more Pythonic way of doing it. I had a look at [`np.put`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html#numpy.put) and [`np.place`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.place.html#numpy.place) but they don't seem to be exactly what I need.

Comment: is `wgt[:, :, lev_idx[ii,jj]-1] = wgt_A` working instead of the loops?  (same change for the 2nd line)

Comment: Since `ii` and `jj` are the loop variables, I don't think so...

Comment: oh, I mean directly `wgt[:, :, lev_idx-1] = wgt_A`